# DIVs refuse to be next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have to div's that will not go next to each other. The menu on the left keeps going below and I can not bring it up. I have tried using "top:-..." but it will not work! Please help!

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<title>Design At Ease - Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><a class="logoclass" href="index.html">DesignAtEase.com</a></div>
<ul id="headerlinks">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="coding.html">Coding</a></li>
<li><a href="graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
<li><a href="database.html">Database</a></li>
<li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul id="quicklinks">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="midwrap"></div>
<a class="Resources">Resources</a>
<ul id="sidelinksleft">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="learn.html">Learn</a></li>
<li><a href="sites.html">Useful Sites</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 html, body {height: 100%;}

* { height: 100%; }

body{
position:relative;
background:#fffffc;
margin: auto auto;
height:100%;
}

#header{
background:#e5e5e5;
height:35px;
width:100%;
border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
}

#headerlinks{
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:right;
margin-right:5%;
bottom:44px;
}

#headerlinks li{
display:inline;
padding-left:25px;
}

#headerlinks li a{
color:#777777;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#headerlinks li a:hover{
color:#a3a3a3;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}


#headerlinks li a:active{
color:#00B2EE;
display:inline;
font-size:18px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}


#logo{
position:relative;
color:black;
margin-left:5%;
top:5px;
}

.logoclass{
color:#212121;
display:inline;
font-size:24px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#quicklinks{
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;;
height:25px;
background:#e5e5e5;
border-bottom: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
top:-66px;
position:relative;
clear: right;
}

#quicklinks li{
position:relative;
top:2px;
display:inline;
padding-right:20px;
}

#quicklinks li a{
color:#777777;
display:inline;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#quicklinks li a:hover{
color:#a3a3a3;
display:inline;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}

#quicklinks li a:active{
color:#00B2EE;
display:inline;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
}


#wrapper{
position:relative;
top:-82px;
margin-right:4%;
margin-left:4%;
width:92%;
height:100%;
background:#fafafa;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
overflow:hidden;
}

#sidelinksleft{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;;
height:25px;
position:relative;
clear: right;
float:left;
margin-left:-25px;
top:15px;
}

#sidelinksleft li{
position:relative;
padding-top:3px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidelinksleft li a{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinksleft li a:hover{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#B0E2FF;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinksleft li a:active{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

.Resources{
color:#000000;;
font-size:16px;
font-family: sans-serif;
position:relative;
margin-left:-156px;
}

#midwrap{
width:70%;
height:90%;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
margin-left:300px;
background:black;
top:10px;
position:relative;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

And I have no more detail, but it is saying I need more so I am typing this random paragraph to make it so I can post my question.

Comment: Which two divs are we talking about here?  I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ9t7/) from the code.

Comment: so you want the header links and the quick links side by side?

Comment: the side menu and the black box "midwrap" "sidelinksleft"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your left-margin (300px) and width of div(70%) is too much for your left nav to stay in place.
div by default is a block element and here in your case it occupies the whole space of the container, So float your div too as you float your left nav and remove clear from left nav to have it sit with the float as that appears before the div. and give `clear:right` on div.

So modified styles:

```
#midwrap {
    width:70%;
    height:90%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    margin-left:100px; /*Reducing this to 100px*/
    background:black;
    top:10px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:right; /*float right*/
    clear: right; /*add this here*/
}

#sidelinksleft {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    position:relative;
    /*removed clear from here*/
    float:left;
    margin-left:-25px;
    top:15px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muqx4/)**

Answer (score 0):

See the following HTML code:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="logo"><a class="logoclass" href="index.html">DesignAtEase.com</a></div>
<ul id="headerlinks">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="coding.html">Coding</a></li>
<li><a href="graphics.html">Graphics</a></li>
<li><a href="database.html">Database</a></li>
<li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="more.html">More</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul id="quicklinks">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="float:left;">
<a class="Resources">Resources</a>
<ul id="sidelinksleft">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="learn.html">Learn</a></li>
<li><a href="sites.html">Useful Sites</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="midwrap"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</body>
```

I created a div holding the menu and used the float: left property.